Console Args in Tauri to Next.js frontend
Im using Tauri.JS with Next.js
There i want to run the console command:
npm run tauri dev --<argument name>=<some value>.
The value of the arg should then be accessable in my JS at src/app/page.tsx.

Depending on what bundler you use for your setup:
For Vite (Tauri uses Vite for most configurations):
npm run tauri dev -- --your-variable=1
# equals to
# vite dev -- --your-variable=1

And then you can access it inside the vite.conf.js using process.argv and pass it to a custom plugin to modify your build.
For usual nextjs, see their docs:
NODE_OPTIONS='--your-variable=1' next

Though accessing the CLI arguments in nextjs will be tricky.
The easiest option would be to setup environment variables:
YOUR_VARIABLE=1 npm run tauri dev

And then you can access them via process.env.YOUR_VARIABLE

The problem is that your command only runs your vite app and not the tauri webview. The right command uses npm run tauri dev. This is where i want to add args but always get errors. Tauri docs say sth about defining args but it doesnt makes it clear how. I already tried adding them to the tauri.config.json but it still wont work.

Do you want to use args inside Rust or Javascript?

Javascript would be great. It should change my route. Like the arg "--app=test" -> "localhost:3000/test".
